# Sobolev space of maps between manifolds with boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces, banach-manifold

Let $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ be compact Riemannian manifolds with non-empty smooth boundary.

> If we consider the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(M,N)$, is there a reference
> on how to model this as a *manifold*?

If it helps, I am specifically interested in the case when $M=N$ and $\partial N\neq \phi$. My guess is that this may look more like a (Banach) manifold with corners but these corners may be defined by infinite families of linearly indepedent functionals rather than a finite family.